# Perform read and write operations when all nodes in particular datacenter are down in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, replication, datastax, cql

I have configured networktopology strategy among two data-centers. one data-center is having 3 nodes and another one with one node.

If all the nodes in one data-center will get down then I am unable to perform any read and write operations through java(using datastax java driver3.1 and cassandra3.7) as well as cql.

Here I am using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch as endpoint_snitch and consistency level ONE.

But as per my requirements application should work even if any one node is up in any data-center.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This should give you what you're looking for https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2016/04/21/cassandra-local_quorum-should-stay-local/

Comment: Thanks. i followed the link. i am getting the below error in run time,  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IZ)V

Comment: And i have used same version of java driver(2.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

set the consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM

Comment: Yes i tried with this consistency too. but no change.